Huge size of nb file after plotting
I have noticed something a little strange in version 14.1. I am importing these big data files (they contain about 100000 rows each) and I am processing and plotting the data. When I save the nb file I end up with something in the range of 120 mb size for the nb file.
I haven't noticed this before. I haven't used data files this big but I have never noticed file size change in nb files containing plots.
Is this something that is supposed to happen? or what can I do to lower the size?

If you import a lot of data into a notebook, it is obvious that the notebook will  be large. Is your data in the range of 120MB? Have you deleted the big data after plotting?

Yesterday, I generated a 100MB contour plot, all of which was stored in .nb file when it was saved.  That's unusually large, but I wanted a hi-res plot. A 100K-pt ListPlot takes about 4.5+MB in WL: RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}] // ListPlot //    ExportString[#, "WL"] & // StringLength.  There are ways to deal with large-output computations. Look up Export, Save, DumpSave, LocalSymbol; or Iconize[plot, Method -> BinarySerialize], though the compressed data is stored in the .nb file.

@MichaelE2 I am now trying to directly export the plots and not display them. It appears that the nb file size has decreased to a reasonable value of around 2mb.

@DanielHuber yes the data is huge, around 600 Mb. I need another strategy! Thank you

As the number of points increases, at some point one needs to rasterize.

@GustavoDelfino can you elaborate on this rasterize please?

@lucian The lines intercept: Range[1000, 50000, 1000] // Map[With[{p = ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {#, 2}]]}, {{#, ByteCount@p}, {#, ByteCount@Rasterize@p}}] &] // Transpose // ListLinePlot
